# Data Grid for Touch Devices

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there any specific data grid for Touch Devices like Tablet and Smartphones. If not then what is the suitable option to show tables in touch devices.

Thanks in advance,

Venkatesh

Answer (score 1):

jQM offers Grid layout as well as Table layout option (Thought the table layout are not well documented)

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/index.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-html.html (Table - right click view source)
- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html (Grid)
- http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/ (960 Grid plugin)

Comment: As I understood, question is for data presentation datagrid UI control, not html organizational grid layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Column-Toggle Table Widget could be of use. See http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/table-column-toggle/ and http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-columntoggle/